# How to use ordinal scale in d3 to return month names

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use d3.scaleOrdinal() to return corresponding monthNames for a set of data. The month is provided by an integer ranging from 1 to 12 in the original set of data, which can be found here. (I manually added in a monthName field in each datum object)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json

Here is how I am trying to create the scale

```
var y = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([height, 0]).domain(month);
chart.selectAll('.temp')
       .data(monthlyData)
       .enter().append('rect')
       .attr('class', 'temp')
       .attr('x', function(d){
          return x(new Date(d.year, 0))
       })
       .attr('y', function(d){
          return y(d.monthName)
       })
       .attr('transform', 'translate(30, 0)')
       .attr('width', gridWidth)
       .attr('height', gridHeight)
       .attr('fill', function(d){
           return colorScale(d.variance + data.baseTemperature)
       });
```

However, I get a really strange result where my data is separated into two bands, one at the top and one all the way at the bottom, which can be seen in this codepen

http://codepen.io/redixhumayun/full/ZBgVax/

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `d3.scaleBand` (not `d3.scaleOrdinal`), [like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mONYeO?editors=0010#0).

A [plain ordinal scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleOrdinal) expects both its domain and range to be arrays with the same number of discrete elements—the scale then maps them 1-to-1 to each other.

You instead want a scale that maps an array of discrete elements *onto a continuous range*. For that, a [band scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band-scales) is more suitable.

Alternatively, you *could* work out at exactly what `y` value each month should be displayed at, and use that array as your ordinal scale's range, but that's essentially what a band scale does for you internally anyway.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a charm. I was debating using band scale but I wasn't sure d3 would map it considering my month array was an array of strings and not numbers. Good to know it can!